# How to get data from sqlite in order by text date in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have stored date in sqlite database as text in this format : '1 Jan 99'.
Now I want to get data from sqlite database in order by date.

Already tried :
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY date(dateColumn) DESC
Select *  from Table order  by datetime(datetimeColumn) DESC

Please Help!!

Comment: "stored date in sqlite database as text" how about you convert these dates upon insertion to integer? Then you can sort.

Comment: get the timestamp of the date in `long` and then put it in Sqlite. Its easier to sort.

Comment: @ReazMurshed How would I do that? Please give an example

Answer (score -1):

try the requet SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY dateColumn

Comment: I tried it already...